# Difference between Veneziano amplitude and Virasoro shapiro amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I have been study about Veneziano amplitude and Virasoro Shapiro amplitude. 
I want to summarize this two amplitude in the following way, please check that i am understand them properly.

Veneziano amplitude : they are open string amplitude for disk. 
Usually we called four-open string tachyon on disk as Veneziano amplitude

Virasoro-Shapiro amplitude : they are closed string amplitude for sphere. 
Usually we called four-closed string tachyons on shpere as Virasoro-Shapiro amplitude.

The similarity between Veneziano and Viraosoro-Shaprio amplitude are they both have Regge and hard scattering limit.

---

Is there are more difference and similarity for Veneziano and Virasoro-Shaprio amplitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is the [Kawai-Lewellen-Tye (KLT) relations](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Kawai+Lewellen+Tye+relations), which says that a closed string amplitude is roughly speaking a product of two open string amplitudes. See e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. Z. Bern, *Perturbative Quantum Gravity and its Relation to Gauge Theory,*  [Living Rev. Relativity 5 (2002) 5](http://www.livingreviews.org/lrr-2002-5); Section 3.1.